# Cassandra Data Delete/Write Issue

Tags: cassandra

I am having cassandra installed on 3 nodes where 2 are seed nodes. when I insert or delete data from any of the seed node it removes the entry of data from the table but after few seconds it appears again. even this happens while I insert data in the table. Data inserted which get replicated on the other nodes but after few seconds it disappears from table and again after few seconds it appears in the table again and this is happening repeatedly.

**Configuration of the Nodes are as below :**

3 nodes where 2 are seed nodes
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

all are in same data center with different Rack.

I have created keyspace with below :

'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'

Comment: If you set `consistency=quorum` in cqlsh what results do you get for reading those rows?

Comment: I have set the consistency=quorum and try to read the data then I got below error.
    ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 1 responses." info={'received_responses': 1, 'required_responses': 2, 'consistency': 'QUORUM'}

Comment: Ok so that sounds like one or more nodes in your cluster is not responding to the read request. I would wager you have some nodes exhibiting GC pauses or WARN / ERROR output in the `system.log` (or `debug.log` for later releases)

Comment: Hi markc I have check the system.log and I don't get any kind of error or warning log.